# How to resend double opt-in e-mail for newsletter subscriptions

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

How does one resend the newsletter confirmation (double opt-in) emails to unconfirmed subscribers. Using mage 1.9.0

We recently had a problem resulting in about 400 people signing up for the newsletter without receiving a confirmation email.

Comment: For clarification. It works correctly now, but we have about 400 people who didn't receive the extra confirmation (opt-in) email and I would like to resend the confirmation mail to them

Answer (score 1):

I don't think resend Possible but if you use this wile register time customer got a conformation mail

GO to Your Backend

`Magento Admin Area-> System-> Configuration-> Customers-> Newsletter`. Expand the Subscription Options area and change the Need to Confirm field value to **Yes**.

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say here, but this option has always been turnt on on our client's webshop.

Comment: ok then go to transaction email and load this email template and view the preview mail

Comment: System -> Transaction Emails - > Add new Template -> Template - > Select Newsletter subscription confirmation -> Load template and  Preview template

Comment: it shows content after load template or not